# Android performClick() on spinner

Tags: android-spinner

I am having problem with performClick() method when applied on spinner but only on android 4.0.1 and higher. It works just fine on 2.3 version.

- Devices used for testing
- Nexus 7 tablet and Samsung Ace 2.

In my code below I use setOnItemSelectedListener and not setOnClickListener but anyways it works on 2.3 version.

Thank you very much for help.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
    //do something
    }

  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }
  });
spinner.performClick();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not need `performClick()`. Inside your activity class, try following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  … // other code
  setupSpinner();
}

private void setupSpinner();
  Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
  ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinner_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
  adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
  //do your thing
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
  //do your thing
}
```

Comment: This will only fill spinner, but I need to show it when clicked on some button.